# DirectX xnacollision

Tags: c++, directx

I've been playing with xnacollision in vs 2010 with directX and C++ and I keep getting this error.

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl XNA::IntersectSphereSphere(struct XNA::Sphere const *,struct XNA::Sphere const *)" (?IntersectSphereSphere@XNA@@YAHPBUSphere@1@0@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall PhysicsApp::UpdateScene(float)" (?UpdateScene@PhysicsApp@@UAEXM@Z)   C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Physics 20 Percent Project\PhysicsDemo.obj  PhysicsDemo
```

When I'm doing this

```
XNA::Sphere sphere1, sphere2;
sphere1.Radius = 1.0f;
sphere1.Center = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
sphere2.Radius = 1.0f;
sphere2.Radius = XMFLOAT3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
int collision = XNA::IntersectSphereSphere(&sphere1, &sphere2);
```

I've included the xnacollision.h.

Comment: Note that the XNACollision types are now part of [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) in ``DirectXCollision.h``--no `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

`#include`ing a header file *is not* the only thing you need to do to get things like these to work. You also have to link to the appropriate .lib file, which is what the linker is complaining about. You need to check your linker settings and ensure that your search paths are correct and that the necessary external dependencies have been taken care of.

Comment: Well what .lib file would go with xnacollision? I have all the standard ones for directX in the linker. d3d11.lib
d3dx11d.lib
D3DCompiler.lib
Effects11d.lib
dxerr.lib
dxgi.lib
dxguid.lib

Comment: It actually turns out that in Frank D Luna, a popular writer on many directX books, actually had xnacollision.h and xnacollision.cpp in one of the folders called common. Instead of using the one in the DirectX SDK I gave the path for the one in Frank D Luna's files called common. Which I had already linked in linker. But thanks for setting my mind in the right direction.

Comment: @user Great, I'm glad I was able to help. You should post your solution as an answer and then select it as the answer to your question to help anybody who might experience the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

XNACollision is not just a header. It's both a header and a cpp file that was shipped in the legacy DirectX SDK as part of the Direct3D 9 Collision sample. It's not part of the legacy D3DX11 library.

With the Windows 8.x SDK, DirectXMath includes the collision types from XNACollision.h/.cpp as part of the standard include headers as `DirectXCollision.h` (it's all inline, so there's no .cpp file or .lib). There's an updated version of the [Collision](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DirectXMath-Win32-Sample-f365b9e5) sample that uses it.

See [Introducing DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx).

Since you are using D3DX11 and XNAMath, it's clear you are using the legacy DirectX SDK. Note that these are both deprecated. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx).